# Why are my rendered elements outside the select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to append html to a Content Holder in a dialogue box and as you can see by the image, Mile, Meter and Kilometer are outside the select dropdown. Why is this?

```js
var rows = $('#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
$("#divNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder").html('<select id="listNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder">');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var row = rows[i];
  if (row.UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem) {
    $("#divNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder").append("<option value='" + row.UOMRelatedUnit_Name + "'>" + row.UOMRelatedUnit_Name + "</option>");
  }
}
$("#divNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder").append("</select>");
```

```html
<div id="divNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are appending into the `<div>` and not the `<select>`. Do this way:

```
$("#divNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder select").append("<option value='" + row.UOMRelatedUnit_Name + "'>" + row.UOMRelatedUnit_Name + "</option>");
// --------------------------------------------------- ^^^^^^
```

And you cannot do:

```
$("#divNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder").append("</select>");
```

That's invalid! Either store everything in a `tempAppend` string and then use:

```
$("#divNewUnitOfMeasureDefaultUnitsPurchasePlaceHolder").append(tempAppend);
```